# PHP convert 2 digit year to a 4 digit year

Tags: php, date

I have data coming from the database in a 2 digit year format `13` I am looking to convert this to `2013` I tried the following code below...

```
$result = '13';

$year = date("Y", strtotime($result));
```

But it returned 1969

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can fix this my storing the year in the database with the rest of the number :)

Comment: `$year = '20' + $result`.

Comment: What if date would be 1995 ? to display future dates, i guess this will not work.

Answer (score 29):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '13');
echo $dt->format('Y'); // output: 2013
```

`69` will result in `2069`. `70` will result in `1970`. If you're ok with such a rule then leave as is, otherwise, prepend your own century data according to your own rule.

Comment: unfortunately you've deleted your comment. but, yeah, you were right! thx ;) and of course it *worked* because we have actually 2013 ;) nice bug. hehe

Comment: thats no bug. Its documented on php.net in [createfromformat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) `y: A two digit representation of a year (which is assumed to be in the range 1970-2069, inclusive)`

Answer (score 12):

One important piece of information you haven't included is: how do you think a 2-digit year should be converted to a 4-digit year?

For example, I'm guessing you believe 01/01/13 is in 2013. What about 01/01/23? Is that 2023? Or 1923? Or even 1623?

Most implementations will choose a 100-year period and assume the 2-digits refer to a year within that period.

Simplest example: year is in range 2000-2099.

```
// $shortyear is guaranteed to be in range 00-99
$year = 2000 + $shortyear;
```

What if we want a different range?

```
$baseyear = 1963; // range is 1963-2062
                  // this is, of course, years of Doctor Who!
$shortyear = 81;
$year = 100 + $baseyear + ($shortyear - $baseyear) % 100;
```

Try it out. This uses the modulo function (the bit with %) to calculate the offset from your base year.

Comment: Edited to correct order of operands. Forgive me; I wrote this on my phone!

Answer (score 11):

```
$result = '13';

$year = '20'.$result;

if($year > date('Y')) {
   $year = $year - 100;
}

//80 will be changed to 1980
//12 -> 2012
```

Comment: Works for birthday, assuming no one is more than 100 years old in your dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, especially [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), for this:

```
$result = '13';
// parsing the year as year in YY format
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', $result);
// echo it in YYYY format
echo $dt->format('Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with strtotime.  Try the same thing with strtotime("now").

Answer (score 1):

Simply prepend (add to the front) the string "20" manually:

```
$result = '13';
$year = "20".$result;
echo $year; //returns 2013
```

Comment: it will not work, if date would be 1999, from DB it will return 99 and after appending 20 it will become 2099 which is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

This might be dumbest, but a quick fix would be:

```
$result = '13';
$result = '1/1/20' . $result;
$year = date("Y", strtotime($result)); // Returns 2013
```

Or you can use something like this:

```
date_create_from_format('y', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a date object given a format with `date_create_from_format()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$year = date_create_from_format('y', $result);

echo $year->format('Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a newbie hack and I know this code is quite long.  I stumbled across your question when I was looking for a solution to my problem.  I'm entering data into an HTML form (too lazy to type the 4 digit year) and then writing to a DB and I (for reasons I won't bore you with) want to store the date in a 4 digit year format.  Just the reverse of your issue.

The form returns $date (I know I shouldn't use that word but I did) as 01/01/01.  I determine the current year ($yn) and compare it.  No matter what year entered is if the date is this century it will become 20XX.  But if it's less than 100 (this century) like 89 it will come out 1989.  And it will continue to work in the future as the year changes.  Always good for 100 years.  Hope this helps you.

//  break $date into two strings

```
$datebegin = substr($date, 0,6);

$dateend = substr($date, 6,2);
```

//  get last two digits of current year

```
$yn=date("y");
```

//  determine century

```
if ($dateend > $yn && $dateend < 100)   
{
    $year2=19;
}

elseif ($dateend <= $yn)

{
    $year2=20;
}
```

//  bring both strings back into one

```
$date = $datebegin . $year2 . $dateend;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues importing excel (CSV) DOB fields, with antiquated n.american style date format with 2 digit year. I needed to write proper yyyy-mm-dd to the db. while not perfect, this is what I did:

```
//$col contains the old date stamp with 2 digit year such as 2/10/66 or 5/18/00

$yr = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $col)->format('Y');
if ($yr > date('Y')) $yr = $yr - 100;
$md = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $col)->format('m-d');
$col = $yr . "-" . $md;

//$col now contains a new date stamp, 1966-2-10, or 2000-5-18 resp.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the year is always `20` something then the first answer works, otherwise, there is really no way to do what is being asked **period**. You have no idea if the year is past, current or future century.

Granted, there is not enough information in the question to determine if these dates are always `<= now`, but even then, you would not know if `01` was `1901` or `2001`. Its just not possible.