# Check date format before changing it with PHP

Tags: php, date

I am looking for a way to check a date format before changing the format.  My system allows users to upload spreadsheets of data, and one of this fields is date of birth.

This biggest issue I have run into this so far is `mm/dd/yy` vs `mm/dd/yyyy`.  I have found an example of fixing this on [PHP convert 2 digit year to a 4 digit year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030366/php-convert-2-digit-year-to-a-4-digit-year) however I don't always want to do this.

Is there a way I can check the `PHP` Date format in an If statement?  I don't want to rely on counting as `1/1/1973` is the same amount of digits as `01/01/73`, but the year issue would get messed up still.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can check dateformat before manipulating it.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to check the format? You can use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to manipulate the dates regardless of incoming Year format. Are you basing a decision in your code on whether the year is YY or YYYY?

Comment: You could just split on '/' and check the length of the third element

Comment: The data gets stored as 4 digits, and I also do a check to make sure the user is over a certain age.  Currently when just using strtotime and assigning a format of YYYY-mm-dd is is trying to populate certain users as 20 instead of 19 for the first 2 digits of the year.  How does DateTime handle these 2 digit years if I want to convert them to 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). The [default constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) can interpret your date strings. This should void your need for conditional checks.

```
$date1 = "1/1/1973";
$date2 = "01/01/73";

$dt1 = new DateTime($date1);
$dt2 = new DateTime($date2);

echo $dt1->format("m/d/Y");     // prints as 01/01/1973
echo $dt2->format("m/d/Y");     // prints as 01/01/1973
```

---

**EDIT**

For two digit years below 1970, you can try this, but it will work **if and only if** your current and future data is entered as four digit years. Otherwise people born between 2003 and 2069 will have their birthdays converted to 19xx.

**Note:** *We're using 2003 because the OP indicated that all new entries will be forced to four digit years, and (at the time of posting) no one under 13 will be using the software.*

```
$format = "Y";

if(!is_numeric(substr($date, -4)))      // Checks for 2 digit year
{
    $yy = substr($date, -2);            // Gets 2 digit year
    $format = "y";

    if($yy < 70 && $yy > 2)             // Looking for 1903 to 1969 
    {
        $yy += 1900;

        // Rebuild the date string with 4 digit year
        $date = substr($date, 0, strlen($date) - 2) . $yy;
        $format = "Y";
    }
}

$delimiters = array("/", "-", ".");     // Different date delimiters to check

foreach($delimiters as $delim)
{
    if(strpos($date, $delim) !== false)
    {
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("m" . $delim . "d" . $delim . $format, $date);
    }
}

echo $dt->format("m/d/Y");
```

Comment: Man I wish it was this simple, but it's still putting 2 digit years under 1969 as 20 instead of 19.

Comment: @Kyle, I understand now. The problem here is going to be overlap. What if someone was born on `01/01/15`-- is that `2015` or `1915`? You can't know. I can provide a solution for "fixing" two digit years less than 70, but it's not a good solution and will continue to get worse as we progress into future years.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The good thing is i am asking for a Date of Birth.  So we know 100% that anything over 15 falls into the 19 gap as nobody is born for 2016 yet.  We also know that this software is for working employees only, so we can guess that nobody is using our software under 13.  That means the only time we want it to go to 20 right now is 00, 01, 02.  Any other dates should be 19.  If done correctly we can code this so it always uses this 13 year gap.

Comment: Thanks @mjohns615, this is a good start but still not my ideal solution.  The reason I want to read a form is people using this software won't follow rules.  Your solution is great for mm/dd/yy, but reading a format will allow me to also deal with mm-dd-yy.

Comment: @Kyle, Ok, let's try this one more time and see if it gets any closer. Check the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81451/discussion-between-mjohns615-and-kyle).

Answer (score 0):

Is it then possible for me to include this code in my SQL insert command?
    `'$date = '01/24/2006'; 
     $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
     $sql = "INSERT INTO table SET date = '$date'";`